# cakephp: how to make NOW() work in search condition?

Tags: cakephp, mysql

I'm trying to get all records with date greater then now. I tried this but it doeasnt work:

```
$all_dates = $this->TourDate->find('all', array('conditions' => array('TourDate.date >=' => 'NOW()'), 'order' => array('TourDate.date ASC')));
```

If I replace NOW() with the current date it works. Why's that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I do not use `CakePHP` but I am pretty sure that your `'NOW()'` is parsing to string and finally you got something like

```
TourDate.date >= 'NOW()'
```

Maybe you should just try

```
array('TourDate.date >= NOW()')
```

as a value only instead of spliting it to `key => value` style ?

Comment: yes that made it. I didn't know it was possible to not to use the key => value style. Thank you

Comment: Hint - if some answer is a solution - mark it by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.

Comment: This solution will only work accurately if the your database's timezone is the same as CakePHP's timezone. Also, If your conditions involve the `created` and/or `modified` fields you should bear in mind that these times are CakePHP times. So your condition would be better written `'Model.date >=' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a way to do it with PHP-function istead of MySQL-functions you don't have to use the verbous format `$conditions = array('begin >' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`, MySQL understands the shorter 'c' preset of PHPs date() for ISO 8601 dates with `$conditions = array('begin >' => date('c'))`.

I like this for doing queries like `'begin >' => date('c', strtotime("+4 weeks"))`, which is very readable code and great to debug when you look at the SQL-Queries.

Answer (score 2):

`'conditions' => array('TourDate.date >= NOW()')`

Otherwise, cakephp will quote the NOW() function, and mysql will think of it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

hsz is correct. Cake is interpreting the `NOW()` condition as the string `'NOW()'`. Providing a full SQL snippet in your conditions will work, as hsz suggests.

You might be tempted to use `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in place of `NOW()` (as I suggested in the first version of this answer). **Don't do it!** As hsz points out below, this will prevent the query from being cached.

Comment: If you use `date()` queries will not be cached.

Answer (score -1):

I believe CakePHP strips out any SQL like functions to prevent a SQL injection attacks.  Much as it annoys me, I usually use the date('Y-m-d H:i:s') trick too.

Comment: No, it's not doing it for security purposes.  Cake just takes the value inside the associative array and throws it into string literals for MySQL.  The solution above (putting the NOW() function in the key, not the value) works.  Still weird that you got downvoted for simply being incorrect.